# How to create a QR code of the content in <p /> using qrious?

Tags: javascript, html, qr-code, p-lang

I am trying to include a QR code in a Bill design that I am creating using qrious.js

ALL the examples on the internet use live text input to create the QR code, while I want a QR of the static text that I want. Please give some possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Qrious readme file is very clear. You have to add your static text to value field.

```
var qr = new QRious({
  element: document.getElementById('qr'),
  value: 'Your static text'
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Now that the design I got the design I want I am trying to create the .exe file using VB6, but I cant link qrious.js. How can I do that???

Comment: Search for a qr library visual basic compatible or use visual studio to create a exe file from a JavaScript file

Comment: could you please elaborate the idea of creating an exe file from javascript file? also if u can please give example for qr library visual basic 6.0 compatible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert the qrious.js script before using it and then access the static information in the call to QRious object.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Static link is</p>
    <p id="theLink">https://youtube.com</p>
    <p>QR code</p>
    <canvas id="qr"></canvas>
  
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qrious/4.0.2/qrious.js">    </script>
    <script>
      (function() {
        var qr = new QRious({
          element: document.getElementById('qr'),
          value: document.getElementById('theLink').innerText
        });
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Now that the design I got the design I want I am trying to create the .exe file using VB6, but I cant link qrious.js. How can I do that???

Comment: You can view and follow along this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7IBueVkc8M&ab_channel=JoLadz on YouTube which shows use of ActiveX JLSQRCode.dll file to create QR Code in VB6.